# Mass deletion of user accounts in Local Users and Groups in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I use Delprof2 to delete user accounts from C:\Users and from the Registry and absolutely love it and its effectiveness.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to do a mass deletion of user accounts from Local Users and Groups (Computer→Manage) without deleting certain accounts?  I work for a school district and sometimes get upwards of 100 or so accounts in there and it is a real pain to delete them one at a time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line: [net](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_subcmds.mspx?mfr=true)

Display all local users:

```
net user
```

Delete user account "Mick66PA":

```
net user Mick66PA /delete
```

Simple put all users to be deletd into a batch file (`.bat`) and then execute the batch file.